# Java, connect to mysql file without server

Tags: java, mysql, file

I wonder if it's possible to use the database file from mysql, without having a server running. Just copying the db file and place it somewhere, then use `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table";`
and change it to something like `"jdbc:mysql://C:/Users/me/Desktop/table";`

Will this work or is there a better way?

Comment: I think it is not possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with `Mysql`. [`Sqlite`](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) is a `Serverless` database  designed for this purpose.

Comment: Ah. I see, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for an embedded database, i.e. as you say a library that is able to access a database on a file without a server.

MySQL has an embeddable version: http://www.mysql.com/oem/

You might want to check also H2: http://www.h2database.com/

Or Apache Derby: http://db.apache.org/derby/

Or HSQLDB: http://hsqldb.org/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: You'd have to basically recreate the MySQL daemon in Java. In particular, JDBC would have to know the structures inside of the file. The files are quite complicated, and this would be quite a pain.

This means you would have to basically write your own code capable of parsing and manipulating MySQL files. This would be a horribly complex task.

---

Yes, there is a better way. If you want to use MySQL, *use MySQL*.

Another option would be to use the embedded version of MySQL, or something like SQLite.